# TrackR keep ringing on its own

Tags: gps, tracking-devices

At the beginning of 2014 I purchased a couple of coin sized [TrackR devices](https://thetrackr.com/) to tag my belongings, so I can easily find them. I use an iPhone to connect to them.

My main problem using these devices was that the ringer on these devices keeps on activating on its own at random without any reason, and it keeps ringing constantly until switched off (taking out of the battery from it).

Is this kind of problem a common one? How can I avoid this issue? Or has this problem been addressed already in later versions of these devices? Obviously I don't want to buy the new version on the hope that it's going to work this time.

To clarify, I didn't use it for the thief-like option to ring when it's separated, I've used only option for the tracking purposes. It was ringing especially when disconnected from the phone, but after some long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another idea, also from [trackr's support page](http://support.thetrackr.com/hc/en-us/articles/205738069-My-TrackR-and-Phone-Randomly-Ring).  Again, it's also a feature that can be enabled/disabled, and that is "Device alert."  Basically, it warns when your phone can no longer make a bluetooth connection with your TrackR devices.

> If your TrackR device and/or smart phone is sounding off at seemingly random times, you may have device and/or phone alerts enabled. When “Device alert” is enabled your TrackR device will sound off when the bluetooth connection betwen your TrackR and phone is off. Conversely, when "Phone alert" is enabled your phone will begin to ring when bluetooth connection between your TrackR and phone is lost. To remedy this issue you can turn off phone and device alerts from the TrackR app. To turn off the alerts please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the TrackR app
> 2. Click the icon in the top right corner of the app. This icon will look like 3 blocks stacked on top of each other.
> 3. A menu will slide in with a list of each TrackR device you have connected with. Click the gear cog next to a listed TrackR device.
> 4. Another menu will slide in where you will have the option to turn device and phone alerts on and off. Move them to the off position. Device and Phone separation alert need to be toggled off.
> 5. Repeat the above steps for any other TrackR's you are paired with.

For more information, check out the article referenced.

Answer (score 3):

If this only happens when the phone and the trackr's are separated, according to [trackr's support page](http://support.thetrackr.com/hc/en-us/articles/200472996-Device-And-Phone-Keep-Ringing-When-I-Separate-),

> This separation alert is an intended functionality. If you would like to disable this feature please check device settings to make sure that both iPhone Separation Alert and Device Separation Alert have the toggle set to the 'off' position (To change the settings go to the menu at the top right corner of the app >Select the device name >Tap the gear icon)

In other words, this is actually a feature, and is working as intended.  If you do not want this behaviour, you can, as mentioned in their support, disable it in the settings.